# Investing : 403 when getting historical data

Tags: powershell, http-status-code-403, invoke-webrequest

I had a powershell script that worked very well until a few days ago:

```
$uri = 'https://www.investing.com/instruments/HistoricalDataAjax'

$params = @{
    'curr_id'= '951481'
    'smlID'= '2081817'
    'header'= 'STOXX 50 Volatility VSTOXX EUR Historical Data'
    'st_date'= '04/13/2021'
    'end_date'= '04/13/2022'
    'interval_sec'= 'Daily'
    'sort_col'= 'date'
    'sort_ord'= 'DESC'
    'action'= 'historical_data'
}

$headers = @{
    'User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0'
    'X-Requested-With'= 'XMLHttpRequest'
    'Accept'= 'text/html'
    'Accept-Encoding'= 'gzip, deflate'}

$res = Invoke-WebRequest -Method POST -Headers $headers  -Uri $uri -Body $params -ContentType application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

The problem is that now I have a 403 error :

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your free trial probably ended.  See : https://www.investing-support.com/hc/en-us/articles/5927125241105-What-Happens-At-The-End-Of-My-Trial-

Comment: I never had a trial version.

Comment: Something must of changed at server that isn't allowing your connection to complete.  I checked the website and didn't find anything related to authentication or any hep on connecting.  You code is using the same default options and manually connecting with a webbrowser.  I would try connecting manually and see if it works.  This may be a cookie issue.  See : https://www.investing.com/about-us/cookie-policy?force_isolation=true